# Generating a backend in Android Studio Fails

Tags: android, google-app-engine

Using 0.5.5 from the Canary Channel.

Chose the third option to generate a backend in Java with messaging.

It went into a sync with Gradle and that all worked, but then when I go to run it, get this error:

[image]

The path it has seems insane, off ~/.gradle/appengine-sdk I did a search off home and there is no /appengine-sdk anywhere. These are beta releases but surprised this just fails in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the tutorial doesn't tell you this: you have to install it yourself. Actually quite simple, go to:

[Google App Engine Download](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads?csw=1)

Then when you do Run and the error comes up, just point it to wherever you dropped the folder.